# Change fieldname in the ValidationSummary

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have pretty straight-forward input form which has some validation.  I am using the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface to hande the validation.

On the form I have a combobox which is bound the a foreign key (ex ParentID).

If the validation is false (user should select an item from the list), the Validationsummary displays the messages as:

**ParentID** Please select a parent.

This is kinda ugly. How can i override **ParentID** with just **Parent**??

thx for the help

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Display Attribute with the Name property changed to more friendly text on your class:

```
public class Child
{
    [Display(Name="Parent")]
    public int ParentId {get;set;}

    public int ChildId {get;set;}

    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

DisplayAttribute class can be found in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx

Comment: Good advice. But I am using self-tracking entities, so the class and properties are generated by the T4 template... I could change this, but it would be overwritten next time the T4 template ran.  Any advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: You can create metadata class in partial class as per link below. The property you want to affect needs to exist unchanged in generated code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx